# Repetitive numbers not matched by RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I am using RegEx in Java to classify phone numbers and I am stuck finding consecutive repeating numbers.

Why is this RegEx

```
9{4}([0-8]\1{2})([0-9]\1{3})[0-9]
```

Not matching this string

```
9999227771
```

Comment: Because first back-reference is referring itself and incorrect repeater count. [`9{4}([0-8])\1{1}([0-9])\2{2}[0-9]`](https://www.regex101.com/r/Rwvw3N/1)

Comment: You are faster than me @Tushar write your answer as answer :)

Comment: The `\1{1}` is redundant, just `\1` ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the regex

```
9{4}([0-8]\1{2})([0-9]\1{3})[0-9]
```

`([0-8]\1{2})` This is first capturing group and inside that `\1` - [back-reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) refers to itself which will not work.

In the second captured group `([0-9]\1{3})`, you are again referring to first captured group.

Also, both the back-references are repeated `n` times which should be `n-1` as first number is matched by the capturing group.

Here is corrected regex

```
9{4}([0-8])\1([0-9])\2{2}[0-9]
```

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://www.regex101.com/r/Rwvw3N/1)

1. `9{4}`: Repeat `9` four times. i.e. 9999
2. `([0-8])\1`: Match a number in the given range and match the same number again, thus `\1`.
3. `([0-9])\2{2}`: Match a digit and follow it by same digit twice

Note: To match exact phone numbers, use [anchors `^` and `$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).